# How to provide label for montage by text file

Tags: images, imagemagick, photomontage

I use `Ubuntu 14.0.4`. We can use this command of `ImageMagick` to label each image by it's name:

```
montage -label '%t' -size 512x512 "./img/*.*[120x90]" -geometry +5+5 photo.png
```

I want to label images by list of strings, which is written in a text file. [Docs say](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#label):

> -label name
>
> assign a label to an image.
>
> Use this option to assign a specific label to the image ... 
>   If the first character of string is ***@***, the image label is read from a
>   file titled by the remaining characters in the string. Labels in a
>   file are literal, no embedded formatting characters are recognized.

But I could not use a file to provide label. I use a command like this:

```
montage -label @un.txt -size 512x512 "./img/*.*[120x90]" -geometry +5+5 photo.png
```

Above, `un.txt` is the name of text file in `./img/` path. This is a sample result:

[image]

In result, all images labeled by string `@un.txt` instead of content of `un.txt`. Also I get this error in `terminal`:

> montage.im6: improper image header `./img/un.txt' @
>   error/txt.c/ReadTXTImage/429

If I **move** `un.txt` to the current (`.`) directory and run above command again, I will get this image (there is no label) and below error:

[image]

> montage.im6: not authorized `@un.txt' @
>   error/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/2959.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With attention to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39377759/1043882), I found it is probably related to the vulnerability discovered in ImageMagick ([here](https://imagetragick.com/)), so I updated my site policy file  by removing `<policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*" />` line from `/etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml`. Now `montage` reads from file.